# Expand ratio of gamma functions into series

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

From the function 
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha ,x)}{\Gamma(\alpha)},$$
where $\Gamma$'s are the usual gamma and incomplete gamma functions, can we write this function into a series of $\alpha$? Meanwhile, how about the inverse of the gamma function,
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}?$$

Comment: A series expansion around which point?

Comment: Any point. Any references?